# How do extractors get damaged?

Tags: warframe

Extractors can take damage while deployed. That's as much info as the game gives, and that's obviously not enough.

What are the specific rules for deployed extractors taking damage? Are they only vulnerable during specific parts of their work cycles? How much damage do they take per hit? Does it matter what planet it's deployed to? Is there any way to avoid this damage?

And as always, I'll record my own observations here and see if a pattern emerges.

- Titan Extractor, deployed to Mercury, took 29% damage while active.
- Titan Extractor, deployed to Mercury, took 37% damage while active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, the extractors:

- take damage (only) while their work cycles. when they are done and still alive, they don't loose any  more health
- the more damage the higher the planet

on earth i think i never took more than 45% damage. can always do two runs without loosing it entirely there

It is also worth noting that Extractors will heal over time if you keep them put away, not extracting or waiting on a planet.

Comment: Thanks. So is leaving an undamaged extractor working overnight _always_ safe? Can it take multiple hits over one work cycle or be destroyed in one hit?

Comment: I never deployed an extractor on a higher planet than phobos/saturn, so i dont know the damage it takes on..say Pluto.    It can't get multiple hits like (taking example from above) twice or triple the 45%. never expirienced that.

Answer (score 1):

An extractor can't die in one run, so it can't get hit more then 99%. If you deploy your extractor at 100% then he'll live we's done. So extracting overnight isn't a problem if you use a 100% health extractor.

What I have done is: I made multiple extractors but I can only extract one at a time because of my mastery rank. but when one extractor is damaged and is ready to come back to me I can deploy another one that I made and then the one that got damaged can heal up etc.